# Allow devices in in a VPN direct access to the internet in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, route, site-to-site-vpn, bgp

Is it possible to route all traffic from a site-to-site VPN connection to the public internet?

Currently, I have set up Squid as a proxy. Since I need to forward also non-http/s protocols I would prefer that the devices connect directly to the internet.

Can a VPC be configured for this?
May something like BGP solve this issue?

Comment: After reading your question I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, or why.

Comment: I suggest revising your question to be more precise on what you want to accomplish and the motivation. It sounds like you want Internet traffic from on-premise to use your VPC. If so, squid can proxy HTTP/S traffic. Other traffic types might be more difficult. Also, BGP vs. static routing on the VGW probably isn't relevant. Keep data transfer pricing in mind as you think about what you want to achieve. The Open Guide to AWS has a great table to summarize data transfer pricing. See https://github.com/open-guides/og-aws#aws-data-transfer-costs.